# Css transition on element that changes position on mousehover

Tags: css

I have a Box that elevates when the user has his mouse hovering this box, and I do this with :

```css
.box:hover { 
     position: relative; 
     top: -10px;
}
```

I would like to know if it possible to make a smooth transition with the `transition` property ?

If not, How should i go about getting this smooth effect ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CSS `transition` property. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Here is an example:

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  transition: top 1000ms ease-in;
  width: 50px;
}
.box:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Hey</div>
```

Comment: Adding position relative to the hover state has no effect on the desired result. Are you saying that the box class does not have positioning? How is it positioned then?

Comment: I am sorry, i am being completely stupid ... Your answer is correct; i forgot to add `top: 0px` to `.hover` that is why it wasn't working . 
Hard to do a transition if they is nothing to transcend from =p

Comment: I want to delete post, but will you loose your +1 ??

Comment: IMHO, there is never a stupid question, just stupid answers. You should leave it for other users that may have the same issue.